# (python 2.7.11) loading a binary file and stuck

Tags: string, python-2.7, variables, binary, variable-assignment

I am using Anaconda with Spyder as editor and Python 2.7.11, freshly updated.
After the last update, my library functions were not working anymore, do I did lot of debugging and I isolated the problem.
It seems that I am not anymore able to load a binary file, assigning the result to a variable.
So, If I do this:

```
filename="example.dat"
f = open(filename, "rb") # opening for [r]eading as [b]inary
print f.read(4)
f.close()
```

It is working well and I get "�o" in the spyder console. If I do

```
filename="example.dat"
f = open(filename, "rb") # opening for [r]eading as [b]inary
a=f.read(4)
f.close()
```

then spyder is stuck without hope.
Why? It was working before the upgrade. Is there something that I can do to overcome this problem? I have lot of functions that are reading certain part of a file as binary, then having the result stored in some variables to write it later.
Thanks

Comment: In what way is it "stuck"?

Comment: stuck= it is not responding, you cannot close it. freezed. 
Ah, the installation is on OSX

Comment: I Isolated the problem.
Actually it is a problem of Python Console.

Comment: @Maurizio ever solve this? I'm having the exact problem now

Comment: Yes....I switched to Python 3